# Android action bar doesn't show at all (KitKat)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Got a small problem with the action bar in KitKat 4.4.2. It doesn't show at all...

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Activity:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_pre_login, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.login:
            Log.d("menu worked: ", "menu worked");
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

What's happening is the overflow menu, or its items do not show whatsoever. Returning true or super() doesn't work. Any ideas what's causing this?

Thanks

Comment: What's your 'AppTheme'?

Comment: post your menu_pre_login xml

Comment: Reeeeally sorry, I've got it to work by adding the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){}` methods to the main activity that launches, and not just on one. It appears on all activities

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Disclaimer: This was copied from the OP's comment under the question</sub>

I've got it to work by adding the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){}` methods to the main activity that launches, and not just on one. It appears on all activities.